# Passing C structures from main golang code to function in a different golang package

Tags: go, cgo

I am trying to pass C structure from the main golang code to different package and getting the typecast error.

### Code snippet

C header file test.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct err_struct {
        int   errnum;
};
```

Golang package test

```
package test
//#include<test.h>
import "C"
func ConvertCtoGoError(err_struct *C.struct_err_struct) {
   //some code
}
```

golang main code

```
package main
import (
        "./lib"
        "fmt"
       )   
/*
#include"lib/test.h"

struct err_struct initialize_structure() 
{
    struct err_struct err;
    err.errnum = 102;
    return err;

}
 */
import "C" 
func main() {
    go_struct:= C.initialize_structure()
    new_struct:= test.ConvertCtoGoError(&go_struct)

}
```

While compiling the main code I am getting the following error:
cannot convert &go_struct (type *_Ctype_struct_err_struct) to type *test._Ctype_struct_err_struct

When I try to typecast the variable it is giving the following error :
 cannot refer to unexported name test._Ctype_struct_dd_err_struct
 cannot convert &go_struct (type *_Ctype_struct_err_struct) to type *test._Ctype_struct_err_struct

Please help me in solving this

Answer (score 4):

According to go docs https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/,

> "Cgo translates C types into equivalent unexported Go types. Because the translations are unexported, a Go package should not expose C types in its exported API: a C type used in one Go package is different from the same C type used in another."

A github issue regarding this can be found here:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13467

**As of now,it is advised,not to expose C types in an exported API**